# Making Android device visible as USB device

Tags: usb, virtualbox, android

I have an Android smartphone connected to my Kubuntu box with a USB cable.  I've figured out how to transfer files, but I need something more: making the Android device visible *as a USB device*.  For instance, if I use VirtualBox and look at its list of USB devices, I want to see the Android,and I don't.  I need this in order to use PC Suite for syncing the contacts and calendar.  Is it possible to do this?  (I have adb installed and MTP file transfer working.)

Comment: Having your device (smartphone) appear as **MTP** or **USB-storage** is an **Android** setting. Which setting have you used?

Comment: There are four settings on the Android: charge only, Media Sync (MTP), USB tethering, and PC Software.  I've tried all of them and none make the USB visible.  I usually leave the setting at Media Sync.

Answer (score 1):

What I done is that when I booted up the Virtual Machine, I opened up the Devices tab and from the dropdown menu I seen my phone and I checked it. Does that work for you?

Comment: NVM Just realised this is five years old.

Answer (score 0):

When you plug in your phone, it is listed with other USB devices. You can use `lsusb` command to see the list. If VirtualBox does not see it, it is the fault of VirtualBox only. Try adding device manually, by copying vendor ID and Device ID from `lsusb` list to VirtualBox settings.

Comment: I can't specify the device in VirtualBox because it says there are no USB devices available, so I never get to the point where I can specify the IDs.  I've tried running LG PC Suite under Wine, but it can't find any USB devices either.  I've been running lsb all along,but the device code keeps changing

Comment: There is a button "Create empty device" in VirtualBox. With it you can even add device that is not present at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Install Oracles extension pack to have a USB2 host controller. Beware though if you're a corporate and not a personal user, there are license liabilities with the extensions last I read.

If you recently installed Virtualbox, you're not yet part of the group that can make the USB devices available. Didn't check if virtualbox assigns the user on install, but to go ahead, use `sudo usermod -aG vboxusers <youruser>` and relogin/reboot to have the group assigned.

Optionally update the Extensions in the VM (Microsofts mdoern.ie trial VM images in my case) - you can do this by downloading the .iso and mounting in in the VM as an optical drive.

Then go to the Virtualmachine settings, enable USB and go from USB1.1 to 2.0 and add a "Filter" fitting your device. The available USB devices should be offered on right click in the filters.